# Avoid notice: Undefined property in stdClass

Tags: php, notice

```
$a = (object)['foo' => 'bar'];
$a->baz;
```

The `$a->baz` call returns `NULL` but also raises a notice `Undefined property..`. Getting null is fine with me when a property doesn't exist but is there any way to suppress this particular notice (from configuration or something, not with if statements or @ symbols, that's obvious) but keep seeing other notices?

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution would be to create a custom std class which is using the `__get` magic method:

```
class customStdClass
{
    public function __get($name)
    {
        if (!isset($this->$name)) {
            return null;
        }

        return $this->$name;
    }

    public static function fromArray($attributes)
    {
        $object = new self();

        foreach ($attributes as $name => $value) {
            $object->$name = $value;
        }

        return $object;
    }
}
```

You can use it like:

```
$object = customStdClass::fromArray(['foo' => 'bar']);
echo $object->foo;
echo $object->baz; // no warning here
```

Comment: Yes, that is what I have currently done and what I'm attempting to avoid.